# help in correcting the syntax error of the below create table with as with multiple select

Tags: oracle, ddl

Please help to correct the syntax of the below. I am from a math background trying to use Oracle. The command helps me permute the columns and put them in one table.

```
create table newsample  AS 
(
select(
(select h1.E1,h1.E2,h1.E3,h1.E4 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E1,h1.E2,h1.E4,h1.E3 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E1,h1.E3,h1.E2,h1.E4 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E1,h1.E3,h1.E4,h1.E2 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E1,h1.E4,h1.E2,h1.E3 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E1,h1.E4,h1.E3,h1.E2 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E2,h1.E1,h1.E3,h1.E4 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E2,h1.E1,h1.E4,h1.E3 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E2,h1.E3,h1.E1,h1.E4 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E2,h1.E3,h1.E4,h1.E1 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E2,h1.E4,h1.E1,h1.E3 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E2,h1.E4,h1.E3,h1.E1 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E3,h1.E1,h1.E2,h1.E4 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E3,h1.E1,h1.E4,h1.E2 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E3,h1.E2,h1.E1,h1.E4 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E3,h1.E2,h1.E4,h1.E1 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E3,h1.E4,h1.E1,h1.E2 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E3,h1.E4,h1.E2,h1.E1 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E4,h1.E1,h1.E2,h1.E3 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E4,h1.E1,h1.E3,h1.E2 from sample h1),
(select h1.E4,h1.E2,h1.E1,h1.E3 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E4,h1.E2,h1.E3,h1.E1 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E4,h1.E3,h1.E1,h1.E2 from sample1 h1),
(select h1.E4,h1.E3,h1.E2,h1.E1 from sample1 h1)))
```

> Error at Command Line:4 Column:49
>   Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
>   00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

```
CREATE TABLE "SYSTEM"."SAMPLE1" 
       (    "E1" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
      "E2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
      "E3" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE),
      "E4" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)
       ) PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 
     NOCOMPRESS LOGGING
      STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645
      PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
      TABLESPACE "SYSTEM" ;
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? How many columns do you expect the result to have? It looks like you just want `create table newsample  AS select h1.E1,h1.E2,h1.E3,h1.E4 from sample1 h1 union all select h1.E1,h1.E2,h1.E4,h1.E3 from sample1 h1 union all ...` (no parentheses needed)

Comment: Yes is got it but need it dynamic minimum 12 columns computation then goes slow any help

Comment: It's just worth mentioning that it is not a good idea to be creating objects in the SYSTEM schema. Best bet is to create a user schema and use that instead.

Comment: 100% sir as I am new to it I had done it will it have impact on the speed of execution if  I create separate schema I have faster speed

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference to speed but is bad practice. A user schema is the place for your user work. Let Oracle use the SYS and SYSTEM schema and tablespaces just for itself (and 3rd party applications sometimes). If you are logged on as SYSTEM you can accidentally break stuff that could prove difficult to fix, especially if you are new to Oracle.

Comment: @BriteSponge: it will become a performance problem if the `system` tablespace grows indefinitely. Especially because you can't shrink the system tablespace later.

Comment: Program takes huge takes huge time if there 12 columns and still any good query better for the permutations of rows in the same table

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result by using **`UNION ALL`** .
Take help of following example for understanding:

```
create table empnew as select * from employees union all select * from employees;
```

As @a_horse_with_no_name perfectly mentioned !

Comment: How to make it dynamic and more fast computional any new sql query

Comment: To make it dynamic you can use  **substitution variables**  "&"